# Transpile TypeScript In Memory With Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, code-translation

Is there a way to transpile TypeScript in memory with Node? I would like to be able to get the generated JavaScript in memory.

Comment: You can load the compiler into node, which modules like gulp-typescript do. Not sure if they operate fully in-memory.

Comment: Assuming by "in memory" you just mean "not written to a file" then yeah, you can use gulp-tsc to compile the TypeScript and then pipe it anywhere you want. I'm sure there are tons of examples of this online, but if you'd liek an example- here's one of my gulpfiles that uses gulp-tsc: https://github.com/bvaughn/task-runner/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L97

Comment: Transpile it to a file, read it into memory and delete the file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. TypeScript provides a a `ts.transpileModule` function:

```
const ts = require('typescript');
const source = "let x: string  = 'hello world'";
const result = ts.transpileModule(source, { compilerOptions: { module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }});
console.log(result.outputText); // var x = 'hello world';
```

## More

- From the TypeScript wiki : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-simple-transform-function

Comment: Typescript-Simple is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3):

We ended up developing our own solution based on the native TypeScript **transpileModule** functionality.

**FROM TYPESCRIPT DOCS**

TranspileModule will compile source text from 'input' argument using specified compiler options. If no options are provided - it will use a set of default compiler options. Extra compiler options that will unconditionally be used by this function are:

- isolatedModules = true
- allowNonTsExtensions = true
- noLib = true
- noResolve = true

**transpile()** - This code will transpile TypeScript to JavaScript (typescriptServices.min.js from [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) is required):

```
export function transpile(tscode: string): TYPE.EVENT {

    interface TranspileOptions {
        compilerOptions?: any
        fileName?: string;
        reportDiagnostics?: boolean;
        moduleName?: string;
        renamedDependencies?: any;
    }

    interface TranspileOutput {
        outputText: string;
        diagnostics?: any[];
        sourceMapText?: string;
    }

    let compilerOptions: ts.CompilerOptions = {
        isolatedModules: false
    }

    let options: TranspileOptions = {
        compilerOptions: compilerOptions,
        reportDiagnostics: true
        // moduleName: modulename
    }

    let info: TYPE.EVENT;

    try {

        // Transpile the ts code to js.
        let ret: TranspileOutput = ts.transpileModule(tscode, options);

        // If diagnostics were returned.
        // NOTE: The transpiler is currently always return a message (code=5047) about 'isolatedModules', which
        // is not relavent for our use. If there is more than one row than there is in fact an error.
        if (ret.diagnostics && ret.diagnostics.length > 0) {

            let code = ret.diagnostics[0].code;

            if (code == 5047) {
                return (info = {
                    success: true,
                    returnvalue: ret.outputText,
                    caller: LibCore.getFunctionName(arguments)
                })
            } else {

                let text = ret.diagnostics[0].messageText;
                // let hint = ret.diagnostics[0].file.parseDiagnostics[0].file.nextContainer.symbol.name;

                return (info = {
                    success: false,
                    returnvalue: ret.diagnostics,
                    message: `Syntax error: ${text} Code: ${code}`,
                    caller: LibCore.getFunctionName(arguments)
                })
            }

        } else {
            return (info = {
                success: true,
                returnvalue: ret.outputText,
                caller: LibCore.getFunctionName(arguments)
            })
        }

    } catch (e) {
        return (info = {
            success: false,
            message: e.message,
            caller: LibCore.getFunctionName(arguments)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Do you know how to get the definitions `.d.ts` output from the API?

Comment: Would have been nice to see the import-statements as wel.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but if your main reason for wanting to try in-memory compiler is performance, what worked for me was resetting `types` and `lib` in `compilerOptions`.

```
const program: ts.Program = createProgram([entryFile], {
  types: [],
  lib: [],
});
```

My build speedup from 10 seconds to 100ms. I didn't need external types and libs in my project, so that was an easy fix for me.